# How to find POI along geojson polyline, preferably using python?

Tags: python, gis, openstreetmap, geojson, osrm

I would like to find POIs along polyline (osrm route). Preferably just on the right side of the route.

For example: [image: enter link description here]

The route is blue, I would like to find the green bus stop.

I have pulled all bus stops in certain area using overpass api and stored them as .geojson file. I am wondering whether there is any software available which would do the work for me.
If there isn't I think I should somehow make a parallel polyline few meters to the right of the existing one. And then connect them into polygon to check whether there are any appropriate POIs in it. But the problem is that this is not ordinary cartesian coordinate system and I am somehow lost.

Comment: Hm, maybe TURF with js2py will do the work

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using Turf.js and Naked.
I wrote 2 small javascripts - first for creating parallel route and the second for checking which points are inside polygon. I used Turf.js in both scripts and Naked to execute them from Python. Data is being sent over temporary geojson files.